# волнообразная граница блока

Tags: html, css

Как сделать волнообразную границу блока?[image: блок с волнообразной границей]

Comment: Нажмите F12 и изучите код элемента. Скорее всего такое обрамление элемента сделано с помощью псевдоэлементов `::after` и `::before`

Answer (score 6):

Вот так это можно сделать помощи `svg path` и `quadratic bezier curves`

```html
<body style="margin:0">
  <svg viewbox="0 0 100 130" width="100vw">
    <defs>
      <linearGradient id="gradient" x2="1" y2="1">
        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#6466a9" />
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#7bb3e4" />
      </linearGradient>
      <mask id="mask">
        <circle r="6"  cx="25" cy="35" fill="#555"></circle>
        <circle r="2"  cx="15" cy="30" fill="#555"></circle>
        <circle r="3"  cx="10" cy="40" fill="#555"></circle>
        <circle r="8"  cx="20" cy="40" fill="white"></circle>
        <circle r="10" cx="30" cy="50" fill="white"></circle>
        <circle r="11" cx="20" cy="50" fill="white"></circle>
        <circle r="6"  cx="30" cy="40" fill="white"></circle>
      </mask>
    </defs>
    <path fill="url(#gradient)" d="M0,10q25,10,50,0q25,-10,50,0v110q-25,-10,-50,0q-25,10,-50,0z"></path>
    <text x="50" y="20">Наши батуты самые батутистые</text>
    <text x="50" y="25">батуты</text>
    <g>
      <image xlink:href="https://picsum.photos/id/101/300/300" 
             mask="url(#mask)" x="5" y="25" width="40" height="40"></image>
       <text x="25" y="65">батуты батуты батуты батуты батуты батуты</text>
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(50,0)">
      <image xlink:href="https://picsum.photos/id/102/300/300"
             mask="url(#mask)" x="5" y="25" width="40" height="40"></image>
      <text x="25" y="65">батуты батуты батуты батуты батуты батуты</text>
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(50,40)">       
      <image xlink:href="https://picsum.photos/id/103/300/300"
             mask="url(#mask)" x="5" y="25" width="40" height="40"></image>
      <text x="25" y="65">батуты батуты батуты батуты батуты батуты</text>
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(0,40)">       
      <image xlink:href="https://picsum.photos/id/104/300/300"
             mask="url(#mask)" x="5" y="25" width="40" height="40"></image>
      <text x="25" y="65">батуты батуты батуты батуты батуты батуты</text>
    </g>       
    <style>
      text {
        text-anchor: middle;
        dominant-baseline: middle;
        font-size:5px;
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
      }
      
      g text {
        font-size:2px;
      }
    </style>
  </svg> 
</body>
```

Comment: Понятно. но как информацию внутрь запихнуть?

Comment: @николай внутрь - никак, а вот поверх...

Answer (score 2):

Посмотрел я этот сайт.

Там берут картинку с белым цветом с одного края и прозрачными волнами с другого края и накладывают её как фон псевдоэлементов.

Картинка уменьшена иначе не влезало.

```css
section {
    position: relative;
}
section:before {
    height: 100px !important;
}
:before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.tenth-screen {
  padding: 10rem 0 5rem;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background: #6260a5;
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, #6260a5 0%, #7db9e8 100%);
  /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, #6260a5 0%, #7db9e8 100%);
  /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #6260a5 0%, #7db9e8 100%);
  /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#6260a5", endColorstr="#7db9e8", GradientType=1);
  /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
}
.container {
    max-width: 1560px;
    padding: 0 25px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
}
.tenth-screen:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: -3px;
  width: 100%;
  /*height: 200px;*/
  background: url("data:image/png;base64,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") center center no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<section class="tenth-screen">
    <div class="container">
        <h2 class="section-title section-title--center section-title--white">Наши батуты удобны для детей и практичны
            для владельцев</h2>
    </div>
</section>
```

Я не понимаю зачем спрашивать если и так понятно что там картинка с прозрачностью. Эту картинку можно только на svg перерисовать в лучшем случае.

Comment: бэкграундами можно, но не так интересно, однако решение есть решение

Comment: Всем большое спасибо.