# Как правильно сверстать изогнутые переходы между экранами?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, svg

помогите понять как правильно сверстать изогнутые переходы между экранами, с учетом того что вверху слайдер (движется только то что на синем фоне) и так же есть изогнутые линии переходящие из первого экрана во второй[image: скриншот макета]

Comment: Раньше сам не знал как делаются такие фоны, мне тогда помогла вот эта статья - https://css-tricks.com/creating-non-rectangular-headers/ .
Можно еще погуглить skewed css background

Answer (score 3):

Или SVG

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 600 300">
  <path d="M0,0 600,0 L600,250 Q300,300 0,250Z" fill="red"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3):

Такой вариант с `svg`:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  height: 500px;
}

.s-1 {
  background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1468233748640-b31327627610?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60) center no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.s-2 {
  position: relative;
  margin: -4rem 0;
  padding: 4rem 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.s-2 svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
}

.inner {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
  padding: 4rem;
}

.s-3 {
  background: #f1f4fe;
}
```

```html
<div class="s-1">

</div>
<div class="s-2">
  <svg preserveAspectRatio="none" viewBox="0 0 500 500" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path d="M500 0C300 80 85 35 0 0V500C182 418 410 465 500 500V0Z" fill="#fbfaff"/>
    </svg>

  <div class="inner">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit, praesentium, deleniti. Iusto minus quos expedita maxime libero laudantium quas ut?
  </div>
</div>
<div class="s-3">

</div>
```

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVe6z.png - от полосок избавься.

Comment: @Qwertiy, убрала

Answer (score 2):

Это делается несколькими svg.

```css
.firstScreen, .firstScreen__bottom {
  background-color: #6823c1;
  color: white;
}  

.firstScreen__bottom svg {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<section class="firstScreen">
  Some content...<br>
  Some content...<br>
  Some content...<br>
</section>
<div class="firstScreen__bottom">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1360 358">
    <path fill="#ffffff" d="M-1,858V500C34.869,658.508,183.691,696.045,314,698c151.8,0,304.764-93.819,461-77,266.02,28.636,313.87,229.511,503,225,47.92-1.143,82-9,82-9v21H-1Z" transform="translate(0 -500)" />
  </svg>
</div>
<div>
  Some other content.
</div>
```

Comment: День добрый, постарайтесь более подробно расписать ответ. Хотя бы краткую выжимку (:

Comment: 1. На svg делать белый оверлей когда можно сделать саму волну - это какое-то извращение. 2. Тебе правка вместо твоего костыля `margin-bottom: -1px;`. 3. Не надо постить ссылки на свои сайты в качестве ответов.

Answer (score 2):

Поможет `border-radius` с разными радиусами закругления по ширине и высоте, хотя можно взять и [сверстать это на `svg`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1002540/188366) как советуют в соседнем ответе

```css
section:nth-child(2n+1) {
  background-color:wheat;
  border-radius: 50% / 10% ;
}

section {
  height:120vh;
  margin-top:-20vh;
}

body {
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<section></section>
<section></section>
<section></section>
<section></section>
<section></section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Тоже на css но более точно выглядит

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: tomato;
  border-radius: 0 0 50% 50%/0 0 100% 100%;
  transform: scale(2.9);
}
```

```html
<div class="item"></div>
```