# Можно ли сделать такое скругление при помощи css?

Tags: css, border

Можно ли скруглить зеленый фон при помощи css?
http://joxi.ru/BA0WKqJTMowRJ2

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1003425/188366

Comment: И вопрос в виде изображения не несёт ни какой полезной информации так как ваша картинка протухнет со временем и ссылка на изображение станет не доступна

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как правильно сверстать изогнутые переходы между экранами?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1003425/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%8b-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Только не спрашивай как этим пользоваться, так как спросили Вы о css подразумевает то что Вы уже знаете css

> смотреть на полный экран

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.item {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.item:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, lightgreen 30%, lightblue 60%);
  border-radius: 0 0 50% 50%/0 0 100% 100%;
  transform: scaleX(2.8);
}

.iteme {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="item"></div>
```

Ну и разумеется забаяненный ответ с SVG

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 600 300"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M0,0 600,0 L600,250 Q300,300 0,250Z" fill="red"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!