# Закругление фона в CSS

Tags: html, css

Часто вижу подобный эффект волны на макетах лэндингов при переходе с одного блока на другой
Возник соответствующий вопрос - как такое реализуется?
Тут же явно не border-radius, есть предположения, что используются псевдоэлементы.
Может, у кого-то есть пример реализации подобного эффекта или код.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения].

Comment: сам фон с такими закруглениями

Comment: картинкой бекграундом,
реализацию всегда можно посмотреть открыв код понравившегося сайта

Comment: дело в том, что реальный сайт с таким фоном не попадался. только на макетах.

Comment: почему вы думаете что это не `border-radius`?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1002540/188366

Answer (score 1):

полукруг https://codepen.io/artem-ayrapetyan/pen/WVQjVX

```
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.item{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item:after{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: green;
  border-radius:0 0 50% 50%/0 0 100% 100%;
  transform: scaleX(1.5);
}
```

волна http://jsfiddle.net/8n17L9ze/

```
#wave {
  position: relative;
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #e0efe3;
}

#wave:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 100% 56%;
  width: 56.66%;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: white;
  right: -5px;
  top: 40px;
}

#wave:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 100% 50%;
    width: 50%;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: #e0efe3;
    left: 0;
    top: 27px;
}
```

что бы сделать так как на скрине, нужно несколько волн наложить одна на одну со смещением,
но проще всего бекграундом картинкой

Comment: не надо вставлять ссылки на сторонние ресурсы, при редактировании сообщения есть специальная кнопка для добавления "сниппетов", которые можно запустить и увидеть результат

Answer (score 1):

Если по хорошему то рисовать надо это в SVG и потом сохранять в отдельный файл с расширением svg и подключать как фон того блока куда надо это применять

Вот  для примера вот этот код из сниппета после просмотра можете скопировать, вставить в текстовый документ и сохранить как background.svg и подключить =>

```html
<svg viewBox="0 30 700 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M0,100 Q150,120 300,60 Q400,30 700,100 L700,200 0,200z" fill="#F7EEE9" />
  <path d="M0,120 Q150,140 300,70 Q400,20 700,100 L700,200 0,200z" fill="#FAF5F2" />
  <path d="M0,140 Q150,136 300,70 Q400,0 700,110 L700,200 0,200z" fill="#004153" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score -1):

Это делается с помощью `border-radius`

```css
.fon {
  width: 100%;
  height: 45%;
  background-color: #494949;
  position: absolute;
  top: 55%;
  left: 0px;
}

.fon1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  background-color: #494949;
  border-radius: 100% 100% 0px 0px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  left: 0px;
}

.icon {
  width: 40%;
  height: 30%;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 40%;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="fon1"></div>
<div class="fon"></div>
<div class="icon"></div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]